# How to use Lodash's unionBy and merge nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, array-merge

Im looking to merge/combine objects in an array each with a series of nested arrays. I want to merge the objects based on a specific key (here `label[1]`). I can use Lodash and unionBy to filter out dublicates by `label[1]`, but how do i keep the values from the filtered items?

The array can look like this:

```
var arr = [{
    "label": ['item', 'private'],
    "values": [1, 2, 3]
  },
  {
    "label": ['item', 'private'],
    "values": [1, 2, 3, 6]
  },
  {
    "label": ['item', 'work'],
    "values": [1, 2, 8, 9]
  },
  {
    "label": ['item', 'private'],
    "values": [1, 2, 4, 5]
  },
  {
    "label": ['item', 'school'],
    "values": [1, 2, 7]
  }
];
```

And the desired output is:

```
var arr = [{
  "label": ["item", "private"],
  "values": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
}, {
  "label": ["item", "work"],
  "values": [1, 2, 8, 9]
}, {
  "label": ["item", "school"],
  "values": [1, 2, 7]
}]
```

Here's a sample which is only half way there.

```js
var arr = [
  { label: ['item','private'], values: [1,2,3] },
  { label: ['item','private'], values: [1,2,3,6] },
  { label: ['item','work'], values: [1,2,8,9] },
  { label: ['item','private'], values: [1,2,4,5] },
  { label: ['item','school'], values: [1,2,7] }
];

var result = _.unionBy(arr, "label[1]");

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks
Lasse

Comment: You say you want to group by `label[1]`, but what happens if the other parts of the label differ? which one should be used in the grouped result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to do this with lodash but I don't think unionBy is the method to do this anyway.

Here is how you can group by label using lodash and then reduce the groups into one value to merge the items of a group.

```js
const arr = [{"label":["item","private"],"values":[1,2,3]},{"label":["item","private"],"values":[1,2,3,6]},{"label":["item","work"],"values":[1,2,8,9]},{"label":["item","private"],"values":[1,2,4,5]},{"label":["item","school"],"values":[1,2,7]}];

console.log(
  Object.values(
    _.groupBy(arr, (item) => item.label.join()),//use lodash group by
  ).map((
    group, //now we have array of array of groups
  ) =>
    group
      .reduce((result, item) => ({
        //reduce a group to one object
        label: result.label, //set label
        values: [
          //set values with unique values of all items
          ...new Set(
            (result.values || []).concat(item.values || []),
          ),
        ],
      })),
  ),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes! nice. This is a great start for me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'd write:

```
const arr2 = _(arr)
    .groupBy(obj => obj.label[1])
    .values()
    .map(objs => ({
        label: objs[0].label,
        values: _(objs).flatMap("values").uniq().value(),
    }))
    .value()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this via **lodash**:

```js
var arr = [{ "label": ['item', 'private'], "values": [1, 2, 3] }, { "label": ['item', 'private'], "values": [1, 2, 3, 6] }, { "label": ['item', 'work'], "values": [1, 2, 8, 9] }, { "label": ['item', 'private'], "values": [1, 2, 4, 5] }, { "label": ['item', 'school'], "values": [1, 2, 7] } ]

const merge = arr => _.reduce(arr, (r,c) => _.union(r, c.values), [])
const result = _(arr).groupBy('label')
 .entries()
 .reduce((r,[k,v]) => (r.push({ label: k.split(','), values: merge(v) }), r), [])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The idea is first to group by via `_.groupBy` and then get the entries (via `_.entries`) so you can form the desired output via `_.reduce`. `_.union` we use to merge the values arrays as part of the final `reduce`.

Here is the **ES6** implementation:

```js
var arr = [{ "label": ['item', 'private'], "values": [1, 2, 3] }, { "label": ['item', 'private'], "values": [1, 2, 3, 6] }, { "label": ['item', 'work'], "values": [1, 2, 8, 9] }, { "label": ['item', 'private'], "values": [1, 2, 4, 5] }, { "label": ['item', 'school'], "values": [1, 2, 7] } ]

const mrg = arr => Array.from(new Set(arr.reduce((r,c) => [...r, ...c.values], [])))
const grp = (arr, k) => arr.reduce((r,c) => (r[c[k]] = [...r[c[k]] || [], c], r), {}) 
const result = Object.entries(grp(arr, 'label'))
  .reduce((r,[k,v]) => (r.push({ label: k.split(','), values: mrg(v) }), r), [])

console.log(result)
```